# netty server getting too many close_wait connections

Tags: netty

We have a server program build to handle the data from client programs.

This server is build to accept the data 50K connections per every min. it works perfectly fine when we don't have huge load on the server. the movement if we experience the load we started getting many close_wait connection which will never gets release by the server.

here is the approach we are doing.

- Server will only close the channel only when the there is a idle time of 3 min for both read and write.
- Its the responsibility of the client to close the connection only when the it done with sending the data to cloud. Server is build to accept multiple messages in the same socket channel

here is the sample code we use

```
public class Server {

public void start() {
   bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(bossThreads);
   workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(workerThreads);

   bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
   bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
   .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .childHandler(new PipelineFactory())
        .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, serverBackLog);

   try {
       // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
       bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",6754));
   } catch (Exception e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
   }
 }
}
```

---

```
class PipelineFactory extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>{

    private static final int SESSION_IDLE_TIME_MIN = 3;

    public void addPipeline(ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
        // Idle Timer
        pipeline.addLast("timeout", new CustomTimeoutHandler(SESSION_IDLE_TIME_MIN, SESSION_IDLE_TIME_MIN, 0, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
        // Message Decoder
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new SomeDecoder());
        // Message Encoder
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new SomeEncoder());
        // Protocol Handler
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new DataHandler());
    }

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
        addPipeline(p);
    }
}
```

Still we don't have a clue why it is producing many close_wait connections.

Can some one point me what we are doing wrong here please?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use ?

```
        .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
```

Comment: we did not use this option. let me try and observe it.Just curiously asking how this is option is going to solve the problem ?

Comment: Nothing to do with CLOSE_WAIT whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the client tries to close the connection from its side but the server does not closes the connection from its side, and the connection remains in CLOSE_WAIT state.

this can happen when not all data in the server read buffer was read by the application, which does no allow the transport level to close the connection after receiving the first FIN from the client.

I know this can happen when you set the channel as unreadable, which prevents the application from receiving new data from the read buffer. in this case the channel will close only when the channel is set as readable or the server application explicitly closes the connection from its side.
if I understand correctly, your server will close such connection after 3 minute because it will be idle. you can see if this is the issue by capturing the the traffic. if the server closes the connection with a reset flag then than can be a sign that the connection was closed when not all data was read from the buffer.

check that you don't, for some reason, set a channel to be unreadable for a long period of time (by mistake or not).

for more information on the TCP connection termination FSM states you can look at this guide [The TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionTermination.htm)

Comment: The transport doesn't close the connection at all, let alone only when the receive buffer is empty. The application has to do that, and it isn't.